# 00230: Service layer has a different projection than the <value>'s projection

Tags: arcgis-pro

Im trying to connect my map to arcgis online and I'm getting this error when I try to Share as a web map.

The [help website provided by esri](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/analyzer-error-messages/00230-service-layer-has-a-different-projection-than-the-projection.htm) just says this

> Solution
>
> Remove the service layer from the map or scene.
>
> If you are not sharing a global scene, change the projection of your map or scene to match the projection of your service layer. For more information on setting the projection of your map or scene, see Specify a coordinate system.

I still dont understand what I am supposed to do to fix this.

Has anyone experienced this?

If I export my layers as shapefiles and use that to make the arconline maps they work.

But i'd like it to update online when I change data on my desktop map. Is that possible? I'm working on a neighborhood map that is intended to be updated over time.

The Layers are NAD 1983 UTM Zone 16n

The Basemap is WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere.

This project is the first time I've used GIS software and map projections have been the most confusing part.

I am using ArcGIS Pro btw

Comment: @BERA Im using ArcGIS Pro not ArcMaps sorry.